# Kafka throttle authentication requests over SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have a scenario where a bunch of producers come online at the exact same time. These use librdkafka. We see that the flood of requests make Kafka open a bunch of file descriptors and eventually run of them and crash. I tried setting the request percentage quota but it looks like it is not applicable to auth requests. I also tried adjusting num.network.threads and num.io.threads but they don't seem to help after a certain limit. Any ideas on how I can throttle the auth requests? I am running v0.11.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: No, not really. We updated the producers to reduce the no of connections and to add random delays on the initial connections attempts.